# Where should mobile apps store user data and how to define when user has to sign up?

Tags: mobile, users, signup-signon, app, flow

1) I am writing here regarding one very important issue.
Just imagine that you've downloaded a daily task manager mobile App.
There are tones of these apps. I am quite confused, because some of them don't force you to log in and create an account. This got me wondering, **is a requirement for the user to have to create an account bad from a UX perspective?**

2) Many GTD apps ("Getting Things Done") have a lot of features and options to detail certain tasks, in order to break it down to smaller ones, schedule it if it has a hard due date, make an appointment by drag & dropping to “Calendar”  and so on. Such apps are quite complex usually. **In this case, from a user perspective is it better to (1) provide a sync/backup option in the app that forces the user to create an account or (2) provide the option of sync/backup up to a 3rd party such as Dropbox or (3) not offer the option at all?**

3) If I am building a daily task manager app (light version of GTD app with an option to share tasks) as a user experience designer I have to work on a user flow diagram. Nowadays, the trend is to let users explor an app without signing up from the beginning. In such case, this app is not a shopping cart app (where user can explore first and once they proceed to checkout - sign in window will pop up). **What/when is the best practice to keep/force user to sign in or register?** What can you advice for an app like daily manager, which is mostly will be used by user to level up his productivity and track his tasks and time.

Comment: Only question 3 falls within the scope of this UX site. The first two questions are about implementation, which would be better asked at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @maxathousand is right, only the last question belongs here. If you're just after a quick answer to the first two, then: (1) Yes, on the device itself (e.g. on iOS you could use NSUserDefault), (2) You're assuming a need to have to use a remote server - why? I don't think a single GTD app I've ever downloaded has required me to sync to a remote server (i.e. they can all be used without having to do this). As for your third question, refer to the answers provided here. Hope this helps. **NOTE: I have now reworded the first two questions to make them fit better within this community**

Comment: Monomeeth, thanks a lot for your assistance and that you've reworded my questions. I will consider it for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(The below answer addresses Question 3 only, as the first two are questions a better fit for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/))</sub>

### Don't make your users create an account for things that don't need an account.

**As a user, I shouldn't need an account until I want to do something that extends beyond my device (and maybe not even then).**

I used to use a ToDo app called Orchestra. They had several features I could use with just the app and my device, such as

- Creating/managing ToDo lists
- Adding events to a calendar/setting due dates
- Creating reminders

### Show your users that creating an account is a benefit rather than an inconvenience.

In order to utilize the following "connected" features, I had to create an account.

- Backup my tasks to *their server*
- Sync my tasks/settings with *another device*
- Share a task with *someone else*

As a user, that makes complete sense. My account is what they tie all of my data and settings to, and how I keep my data secure. **Creating an account at this point in my interaction was a perk rather than an inconvenience.**

Comment: Maxathousand, thanks for your answer. It has clarified things for me.

Comment: One more question: If there are requirements, that the app design should contain sign up & login. And I see that in many to-do apps such as "Any.do", "Wunderlist" there is sign up screen from the beginning in a way to sync data throughout all devices. But if I want to give user an opportunity to use the app as simple grocery list without signing him up yet.

Comment: Only when user will want to make a note/split and manage small tasks/use file-drop capabilities/share task with someone else (extend grocery list app to a gtd let's say) I will ask him to sign up. Is it correct way? For people who want to backup tasks to the server from the beginning, I will put this option somewhere in settings of the app, so it would be optional first.

Comment: I've splitted my question here, cause there were not enough characters.